# Particle movement attached to emitter object rotation

Tags: animation

Here's an inline link with a screen gif of the topic [Gfycat](https://gfycat.com/mixedtedioushoverfly).

Hi there,

how can i do that: rotating an emitter object around z-axis, and the particles do also rotate with the emitter object? The goal would be an animation with a sun emitting sun protuberances and following the sun rotation.

The animated gif is from a Youtube Tutorial i found and i have it made twice meanwhile just to be sure following all the necessary steps.

The Sun is turning on its z-axle, but the Particles doesnt follow the Suns rotation.

I was trying several things, but when the emitter object is turning on its z-axle, the particles doesnt follow the rotation.

This is the Preview Video of the final Sun from the Tutorial from Sardi Pax https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7qDZKfjoi4 and it looks awsome.

What do i am wrong?

Thanks

Bruno

Comment: Hair particles would rotate with the mesh.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but can i do the look of protuberances with hair?